# How to destroy a Ckeditor 5 instance

Tags: ckeditor5

How can I unload a Ckeditor 5 instance from a form object? I can load it with ClassicEditor.create(). I found the editor.destroy() method but it does not work. The Javascript console says "editor.destroy is not a function".

Current testing code is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ckEditor('load')">Start</button><button type="button" onclick="ckEditor('unload')">Stop</button>
<textarea id="welcomeText" class="form-control" tabindex="21" name="txt_welcomeText" rows="10"><p>This is my welcome text.</textarea>
<script>
   function ckEditor(action) {
      editor = ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#welcomeText' ) ).catch( error => {console.error( error );});
      if (action == "unload") editor.destroy();
   }
   </script>
```

Best regards,

George

Answer (score 3):

There's a need to wait for the promise in order to get the CKEditor 5 editor's instance.

```
ClassicEditor.create( element )
   .then( editor => editor.destroy() )
   .catch( err => console.error( err ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me :

```
document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable').ckeditorInstance.destroy()
```

All you have to do is getting the instance , then destroying it ! 
`.ck-editor__editable` is the default class for the CKeditor. 
You can find more explanation in the official documentation : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html#destroying-the-editor

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.